# Can't read std::vector<std::string> C++ type using LLDB python API

Tags: c++, lldb

I'm working on some custom LLDB type formatters for my project but am hitting an issue accessing a specific C++ type via the LLDB python API. I've boiled it down to this test case:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> myVector;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this with:

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -g -o test test.cpp
```

And run in LLDB, breaking in main():

```
(lldb) target create "/tmp/test"
Current executable set to '/tmp/test' (arm64).
(lldb) b main
Breakpoint 1: where = test'main + 24 at test.cpp:7:5, address = 0x00000001000037b4
(lldb) r
Process 73765 launched: '/tmp/test' (arm64)
Process 73765 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x00000001000037b4 test'main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fdfee10) at test.cpp:7:5
   4    std::vector<std::string> myVector;
   5
   6    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
-> 7        return 0;
   8    }
Target 0: (test) stopped.
```

If I query the type of myVector using the LLDB python API, I get a valid type back as expected:

```
(lldb) script -- lldb.frame.statics[0].GetType().name
'std::__1::vector<std::__1::string, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::string> >'
```

But if I then try to look up that type by name, it is not found:

```
(lldb) script -- lldb.target.FindFirstType('std::__1::vector<std::__1::string, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::string> >')
No value
```

It seems to be something related to using std::string as the vector element type. If I change it to int, the above test works ok and FindFirstType returns a valid type.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `std::__1::string` is really `std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>`, maybe that'll work instead?

Comment: There's quite a bit of black magic in the C++ compiler's handling of the "std::string" class, which apparently lldb isn't undoing properly in the type name lookup.  Definitely a bug, feel free to file it with the lldb issues page: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues